# Make file downloadable from android app with web browser

Tags: android, sockets, http, fileserver

I want to let the user download a file from my android app with the web browser on his computer (in local network). 
At first I wrote the code for this feature in eclipse on my computer and it worked fine. But when I try to run it in an android app (the file is copied from the assets path) I am not able to download the file anymore. Firefox just tells me that it couldnt download because the source file could not be read.

This ist my code in the app. It doesnt throw any errors.

```
public class test implements Runnable {

public boolean running = true;
ServerSocket servsock = null;
Context context;
String filename = "test.jar";

public test(Context con){
    this.context=con;
}

public Integer createSocketandStart(){
    for (int i=1234; i<2000; ++i){
        try{
            servsock = new ServerSocket(i);
            servsock.setSoTimeout(1000000);
            new Thread(this).start();
            return i;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("socket error");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void run(){

    File f= new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
    try {

        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

    while (running) {

        try {
            Socket connection = servsock.accept();
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            PrintStream pout = new PrintStream(out);
            InputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);

            pout.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" +
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n" +
                    "Date: " + new Date() + "\r\n" +
                    "Server: FileServer 1.0\r\n\r\n");


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            while (file.available() > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, file.read(buffer));
            }

            out.flush();

            if (connection != null) connection.close();

            file.close();
            pout.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the url you use in the browser? How do you invoke this Runnable?

Comment: I invoke the Runnable by "test dt = new test(this); int socket = dt.createSocketandStart();" in my Activity. I get the URL by the local adress and the returned port number.

Comment: (example: 192.168.2.100:1234)

Comment: I've never seen a Runnable used in this way. How far does it's code flow? Is there a connection? You could give much more info about what is happening. And ofcourse 192.168.2.100:1234 is not a valid url to begin with.

Comment: @brotfreak: You are not sending `Content-Length` or `Connection: close` headers.  You know the file size ahead of time, you need to send it. Or use HTTP 1.1's `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` format instead, which does not rely on `Content-Length`.

Comment: @greenapps: if you type "192.168.2.100:1234" into a web browser, it is going to create a proper `http://192.168.2.100:1234/` URL for itself, connect to 192.168.2.100:1234, and send a `GET` request for `/`.

Comment: @brotfreak: you have an `InputStream` to the original asset file, why are you copying the file into a memory buffer and saving it to the Files folder, and then creating a new `InputStream` to that file? Just send the original `InputStream` as-is, you don't need to waste time and resources with all those extra copies.

Comment: @brotfreak: BTW, did you make sure your Android app has the `INTERNET` permission enabled?

Comment: Yes, the permision is enabled. I tried the headers, but unfortunately it didnt work. As before firefox just shows the download dialog (with the filename and with the content-length header it shows the right file size) but also the error message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The new InputStream was just a test. It also doesnt work with the original stream.

Comment: @brotfreak: Try calling `pout.Flush()` before writing the file data to `out`.  Maybe `pout` did not write the entire HTTP header before you started writing the file. It would really help to see the actual HTTP traffic from a packet sniffer, like Wireshark.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `pout.flush()` does not change anything. While testing i found out that it works when I add `out.flush(); Thread.sleep(100); ` to the file send loop. I just have no idea why.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Any idea?